# Splitting papers into folders

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

In order for sheets of paper to be placed in a folder, they have to be connected with staplers. For example, staplers can hold 10 papers at most. 3 staplers are neeeded to hold together 25 papers. If the first stapler is used for the papers from 1-10, the second from 10-19, and the third from 19-25 then only one folder will be needed. If the first stapler is used for the papers 1-10 the second for 8-18, and the third for 16-25 also only one folder will be needed. If the first stapler is used for the papers from 1-10 , the second from 12-21 and the third from 21-25 three folders will be needed since the first folder will contain from 1-10, the second folder 11, and the third from 12-25.
The arrays a1,a2....an and b1,b2....bn of whole positive numbers represent the papers from ai to bi that are going to be stapled where ai < bi for i = 1,2..n. The input data is L elements and n staplers. The i-th staplerstaples papers from ai to bi where ai and bi are included. If a stapler can hold any number of papers at most, how many are the possible resulting folders?

I have to write an algorithm with O(n) complexity which solves the task if L is of the order of n and an algortihm with O(nlogn) complexity independent from L but I am not sure how to approach the task. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: StackOverflow is not here to write your homework for you. Please read throught the help center to understand how to use the site.

Comment: Don't you mean O(N*L) when L ~= O(N)?

Answer (score 0):

For the O(NlogN) part.

You need to sort the intervals(staplers) based on the start point (the a's array).

You traverse the array of intervals. Keep track of the last page (where the interval closes). If the next interval starts before your last page, update the last page to be max of what you had before the the last page of the next interval. If it starts after the last page then you have a full folder (so add one to the result) and you might have free pages in between that are going to need a folder each.

Pay attention to how you compute the number of pages and make sure you correctly account for free pages before the first stapler and after the last one, as it's easy to make a +/- 1 mistake.

The complexity comes from the sort part. The rest is linear.